# android can't display the bottom of the layout

Tags: android, layout, scrollview

I made an android app that contain scrollview layout and inside it AbsoluteLayout, the problem is I can't display the bottom of the layout it only display  the top of the layout. I tried to use layout_marginBottom in the AbsoluteLayout but it didn't work.

Comment: Use Relative Layout or LinearLayout instead of Absolute..It already deprecated..

Comment: What you want to show on bottom of the layout..

Comment: @Ranjit Pati I added pics in the question.

Comment: why you use scrollview here?

Comment: @Ranjit Pati because the textView more info is long paragraph, it doesn't appear here because I add it in the java file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RelativeLayout` instead of `AbsoluteLayout`. Also don't scroll the total layout. Just scroll the `View` only.

Check it once:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
android:background="@drawable/bg"  >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="TextView" />

</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
    android:text="@string/s3"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout and set left and right margins like

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
lp.leftMargin = x;
lp.topMargin =  y;
```

Answer (score 0):

True , absolute layout is deprecated . Also  , here is a tip :

When creating an xml layout for Android , the easiest way to check for error is using the "graphical layout" tab of the xml layout file . [image: Graphical layout editor] . Use an appropriate device configuration ( match your device ) and the API version , reproduce that error and see if changing the layout parameters help .

Comment: it looks perfect on the graphical layout but when test it in the emulator or on my phone it doesn't show the whole layout.

Answer (score 0):

use property android:fillViewPort=true inside ScrollView as follows

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```